# Perfect Conducting (PC) and Perfect Insulating (PI) boundary conditions for magnetic induction in MHD problems in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: finite-difference, numerics

I understand the computational implementation of the PC and PI bcs in cartesian case. In terms of the magnetic field components for PI, we have $B_x = B_y = B_z = 0$, and for PC, we have $\partial_x B_x = \partial_x B_y = \partial_x B_z = 0$, given that $x$ is the normal direction to the boundary.
Let's say you have a domain bounded by two cylindrical surfaces at radii $R_1$ and $R_2$, in cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$ what would the corresponding bcs on $B_r$, $B_{\theta}$ and $B_z$ be?

Comment: The normal direction in this case is along variable r. Pc would thus read $B_r = \partial_r B_\theta = \partial_r B_z = 0$. Note that you can make a variable change to $(r,\theta,z)$ independently of what basis you write the components of $B$ in (whether that is $e_x$, $e_y$, $e_z$ or a cylindrical basis). Does this answer your question?
EDIT: From a quick search online, I am not finding the same BCs for PC. What I find is that the tangential components of $B$ vanish at the boundary. Are you sure of your boundary conditions? But sticking to what you wrote, I think the above holds.